# Mobile menu bar in css

Tags: html, css, mobile, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

please can someone help me convert the following into a menu bar for a mobile device, ive been trying for ages. i would like it to be 500px and not use bootstrap if at all possible, or if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

```css
#menu {
    width: 21.4vw;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1vw;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 1vw;
    background-color: #CA2A2A;
        border-radius: 0px;
        max-width: 96vw;
    
}
#menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0.5vw 0vw;
    margin: 0px;
}
#menu li { 
    display: block; 

}
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0.5vw 0.5vw 0.5vw 0.5vw;
 font-size: 3vw;
 display:block;
    
}
#menu a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
  <body>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="website.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="breakingnews.html">Breaking News</a></li>
<li><a href="Sport.html">Sport</a></li>
<li><a href="Hulltoday.html">Hull Today</a></li>
<li><a href="Property.html">Property</a></li>
<li><a href="Social.html">Social Media</a></li>
<li><a href="Music.html">Music</a></li>
<li><a href="Reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
<li><a href="Movies.html">Movies</a></li>
<li><a href="Weather.html">Weather</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
    
  </body>
  </html>
```

thanks for the help again.

Answer (score 1):

Hello it looks like you are in need of some [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Media queries allow you to specify specific css depending on the width of the screen your site is being displayed on. You can add a media query for 500px to your css like so:

```
@media (max-width: 500px){
//CSS to be applied to your website when being viewed on screen widths of 500px
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: thanks for that, I'm more struggling with how i would then develop the actual code to get what i want, whatever i try ends up failing in some way

Comment: For example, that you wanted to modify the menu when being viewed on mobile. Aside from minimizing the width of the #menu, you might also want to modify the font size, and maybe padding, etc. I like to do is add my queries and then use something like bitballoon.com to actually post my static files on a domain (free). Once they are on the domain you can import it into something like http://quirktools.com/screenfly/ to test your site on different mobile screens. *Dont forget to also add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> in your <head>.